# Warning: utf8_to_unicode:

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

Recently I switched to VPS from Shared Hosting. Everything is working fine but I am facing two issues, Which are:

1. When I open Admin tools from back-end i get this error:

`Warning: utf8_to_unicode: Illegal sequence identifier in UTF-8 at byte 55599 in /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php on line 110`

However, AdminTools is working fine and I am getting above error on top of the page.

2. My back-end is very slow after switching to VPS, this is strange for me.

I am using latest Joomla 3.3.6 version

I would appreciate if someone can assist in this regard.

Comment: I'd suggest turning on Joomla Debugging in the administrator, and examining the SQL and performance information that is provided at the bottom of the page.  You'll have a better idea where to be looking and be able to provide more information for us to help with. :)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using on your VPS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you need to do:

- Ensure you're using PHP 5.3.29 or above
- Ensure you're using the latest version of Admin Tools (3.4.0)
- Ensure you're using the latest version of the Joomla 3.x series (3.3.6)
- Ensure you have the `mbstring` extension installed in your cPanel

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Current Php version is 5.3.29, along with latest joomla 3.3.6 and latest admintools. I am not familiar with mbstring, can you please guide me in this regard?

Comment: With your VPS server, do you have cPanel or some sort of WHM?

Comment: I found tutorial for enabling mbstring on WHM Cpanel. I just checked it was not enabled, so i am building profile and let you know after finishing process.

Comment: After enabling mbstring I am not getting error anymore. Thank you so much. I am new to VPS, can you recommend me what other things should be and should not be enabled?